# SQL how to select a group of records based on some statistics of this group?

Tags: sql, group-by

Example, I have a record set with three columns:

id,week,count

- 1,1,10;
- 1,2,20;
- 1,3,30;
- 2,1,3;
- 2,2,2;
- 2,3,15;

What I want is just the data of IDs whose average count is > 10. Then, in this example data, the data of id=1 will be selected.

Thanks.

Comment: SELECT id FROM YourTable GROUP BY id HAVING AVG(count) > 10

Comment: @realnumber3012 Post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM YourTable GROUP BY id HAVING AVG(count) > 10
```

Comment: by "Group", only the id is selected, but not the records of this id, am I right?

Comment: Yes you right. You have list ids. USE OPERATOR <IN> AND get data by ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM YourTable GROUP BY id HAVING AVG(count) > 10)
```

Or if you are using an access database (where IN happens to have horrendous performance for whatever reason) you can use:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (SELECT id FROM YourTable GROUP BY id HAVING AVG(count) > 10) AS t1
INNER JOIN YourTable AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, you can also do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, avg(count) over (partition by id) as avgcount
      from t
     ) t
where avgcount > 10
```

Comment: If RDBMS SQL SERVER or ORACLE. You query will work. And here one scan table.

Comment: @realnumber3012 . . . SQL Server 2012, Oracle, Postgres (and lots of databases are based on Postgres), and DB2 all support window functions.